# changing the bg color of an active click function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

basically i have this click function in jquery: (this is just a snippet, not full)

> $('.block').click(function(){
>
> ```
>     var id= $(this).attr('id');
> ```

i want to chnage the background color of the block that has been clicked only, assigned with the id i.e.

> $('.block').click(function(){
>
> ```
>     var id= $(this).attr('id');
> ```
>
> $('.block').css('background-color','grey');

but where do i assign the id, so jquery knows, to only turn the clicked block into grey, not the others, cheers

Comment: on a side not this.id is quicker than $(this).attr('id') becuase it doesn't have to retrieve anything from the DOM

Comment: hey timothy, thanks for your answer, how about when a user clicks another block, i want the old one to turn into white again, and the new one to grey, if you know what i mean!!! :))

Comment: see update. Has an example too.

Comment: @Timothy: `$(this).attr('id')` doesn't access the DOM more than `this.id` (under the covers, it eventually comes down to `this.id`, deep in the bowels of jQuery). But agree with the general point, no need for all of the various function calls and machinations that `$` and `attr` do if you're just retrieving the ID of an element. `id` is one of the nice reliable reflected properties. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS classes are recommended. There are three methods `toggleClass()`, `addClass()` and `removeClass()`

```
$(".block").click(function() { 
    $('.block').removeClass('someClass');//remove the class for all items with class block
    $(this).addClass('someClass');//add the class to the current one
});
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruhley/yp8Jv/) for a working example. I answer your original question you would do this

```
$('.block').click(function(){
    var id= this.id 
    $('#' + id).css('background-color','grey');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.block').click(function(){

    $(this).css('background-color','grey');

});
```

when an element with class `.block` is clicked, that specific element's background is set to grey.

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/ZUE8x/

:)

Comment: how about if i wanted to return the block to th white color again, after another block has been clicked!! :))

Answer (score 0):

To return the blocks to white you could do something like this:

```
$('.block').click(function(){

    //set all blocks to white
    $('.block').css('background-color','white');

    //set the clicked block to grey
    $(this).css('background-color','grey');

});
```